# VBA clearContents does not work well when called from another macro

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone explain me why this simple code works well when alone
and when called in a group with other macro it clears from A1 cell. How it can be fixed?

```
Sub Clear()


Dim LastRowColumnB As Long
LastRowColumnB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("結果").Range("A2:L" & LastRowColumnB).ClearContents


End Sub
```

in belowe code its not working (clearing data from A1):

```
Sub All()

Call Clear
Call deleteSheet
Call dane
Call copyStare
Call copyNowe
Call compare
Call Formula
Call 終了

End Sub
```

Comment: Well it could be that you're not specifying the sheet to find the last row on. Try it as `Sheets("結果").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`. Without specifying the sheet, it defaults to the active sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because LastRowColumnB returns 1 when called in group.
First of all be specified as much as it is possible.
For example:

```
Sub Clear()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("結果")

Dim LastRowColumnB As Long
With ws
   LastRowColumnB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   .Range("A2:L" & LastRowColumnB).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Secondly, You don't have to use call (remember not to use keywords as your modules/function names).

```
Sub All()

Clear
deleteSheet
dane
copyStare
copyNowe
compare
Formula
終了

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped! so it seems that the problem was not setting the sheet name